# Access denied when fetching resource (room) calendar

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I implemented msgraph where I get the resources (rooms)

```
/places/microsoft.graph.room
```

Then, for each resource, I call the endpoint to get the calendar (from the room email address)

```
/users/<ResourceEmail>/calendar
```

It works well with a client using only Microsoft 365 but for another client using Microsoft 365, Azure AD and exchange, I'm not able to get the second call retrieving the calendar, I get this error

```
403 Forbidden: {"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

The scopes are

```
"Calendars.ReadWrite",
"Place.Read.All",
"Directory.ReadWrite.All",
"User.ReadWrite.All",
"offline_access"
```

The account that connected through Oauth2 is admin. We tried to connect to Outlook 365 with this account and I can see the resources and the calendars. We delegated the resource to the admin in Office 365 and Azure, I really don't understand this issue as it works with a client and not the other, there is maybe a misconfiguration in the account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

**1)** Give the **`full access`** to to other users in Office 365. See [Use the EAC to assign permissions to individual mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/recipients/mailbox-permissions?view=exchserver-2019#use-the-eac-to-assign-permissions-to-individual-mailboxes). (you should be able to find the room under Resources. And the process can take up to hours for the changes to propagate through the system and be in effect.)

**2)** Add one more delegated permission: **`Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`** .

Refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference) to know more about permissions

giving **`full access`** to other users and assign **`Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`** delegated permission, which means the delegated users can open the mailbox of User **Room** and do anything except send messages (including access its data).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Is not `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` included in `Calendars.ReadWrite` already? Seems to be a sub scope.

Comment: Can you please check this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-8   there is permission called `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`

Comment: You are right! I'm going to test this!

Comment: is the issue resolved?